# Row Array to Column Array

Tags: arrays, google-sheets

Using Google Sheets Script Editor,
I'm getting an array from a row but need to write it to cells in a column.

This works...

```
    var values1 = [
   [row[1], row[2], row[3], row[4], row[5], row[6], row[7], row[8], row[9], row[11], row[10], row[24]]
 ];

 var range1 = Editsheet.getRange("A1001:L1001");
 range1.setValues(values1);
```

But what I want is...

```
    var values1 = [
   [row[1], row[2], row[3], row[4], row[5], row[6], row[7], row[8], row[9], row[11], row[10], row[24]]
 ];

 var range1 = Editsheet.getRange("D6:D17");
 range1.setValues(values1);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a data array imports from "A1001:L1001" to "D6:D17", the array is necessary to transpose. Now you have an array with 1 row x 12 columns. In this case, the array with 12 rows x 1 column has to be created. The script is as follows.

```
var values1 = [
  [row[1], row[2], row[3], row[4], row[5], row[6], row[7], row[8], row[9], row[11], row[10], row[24]]
];
var values2 = [[i] for each (i in values1[0])]; // Here, transpose value1
var range1 = Editsheet.getRange("D6:D17");
range1.setValues(values2);
```

If you want to transpose from an array with n rows x m columns to the array with m rows x n columns, you can use following script.

```
var values2 = [];
for (i in values1[0]){
  values2.push(values1.map(function(e,j){return e[i]}));
}
```

Comment: Thanks, runs great and I am now getting better execution times!

Comment: I'm glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to modify your code like so

```
//Put each element to be inserted into a row in the sheet into its own array/2 Dimension
 var values1 = [
   [row[1]], [row[2]], [row[3]], [row[4]], [row[5]] ... ,[row[24]]
 ];
// Your range size should match the array size so your range will be from D6:D29 (Total of 1 - 24 = 23 values in aray)
 var range1 = Editsheet.getRange("D6:D29");
// or you do this instead getRange(rowNo,ColNo,NoOFColumn,NoOfRow)
 range1 = Editsheet.getRange(6,4,values1.length,1)
 range1.setValues(values1);
```

You can also use loops to push your row values into a new array like so

```
var values = []
for(var i = 0; i < 24; i++){
  values[i] = []
  values[i][0] = row[i+1]      //Note modifying Row will also modify values
}
var range1 = Editsheet.getRange(6,4,values1.length,1)
range1.setValues(values1);
```

Hope this helps